# Perl MIME-Tools: Content changed of a body-part

Tags: perl, mime

I have the following sample input to a mime-parser (mytest).

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha1; boundary="----=_Part_abc123"

------=_Part_abc123
Content-Type: application/text; name=test.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt

VUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVU
VUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVU
------=_Part_abc123
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature

blabla
------=_Part_abc123--
```

The code is this (just read it in and write it out again).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Parser;

my $fn = "mytest";
my $parser = new MIME::Parser ();
$parser->output_to_core (1);

open (F, $fn);
my $entity = $parser->parse (\*F);
close (F);

open (F, ">mytestnew");
$entity->print (\*F);
close (F);

exit 1;
```

The produced output (mytestnew) is this.

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=sha1; boundary="----=_Part_abc123"

------=_Part_abc123
Content-Type: application/text; name=test.txt
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt

VUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVU
VUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVU

------=_Part_abc123
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature

blabla
------=_Part_abc123--
```

As we can see the content of the 1st part changed (see the VUVU... linebreak).

That is a problem if the signature (2nd part) is used to verify the content. Maybe it is because the base64-encoding is not "pretty". But the verify of the signature does not care about that. It just sees a corrupt content and failes. 
In my sample I cut the signature - the question is not about verifying.

So how can I parse the content, write-out again with MIME-tools AND keep the content unchanged??

Thanks for help!

Comment: `base64 -d` on both strings returns the same output.

Comment: You *cannot* expect the output to be identical if you parse it into memory and write out the parsed representation (unless the format you are parsing is so strict that no variation in representation is possible). I'm thinking your signature generation is broken in the first place if it operates on the MIME representation rather than on the actual contents, but I'm not familiar with PKCS7.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/MIME-tools-5.509/lib/MIME/Tools.pm):

> **Don't plan on printing exactly what you parsed!**
>
> Parsing is a (slightly) lossy operation. Because of things like
>   ambiguities in base64-encoding, the following is not going to spit out
>   its input unchanged in all cases:
>
> ```
> $entity = $parser->parse(\*STDIN);
> $entity->print(\*STDOUT);
> ```
>
> If you're using MIME::Tools to process email, remember to ***save the
>   data you parse if you want to send it on unchanged***. This is vital for
>   things like PGP-signed email.